# How do I capture two textboxes that have no caption and the same class?

Tags: vb.net, api, sendmessage, findwindow, findwindowex

So, I'm trying to capture a window which has 2 textboxes and send some text to both these textboxes. But both textboxes have no caption and the same class name "Edit". So far all I am able to do is capture the first textbox and thats it.

Pasted below is my code.

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Text

Public Class Form1

    Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" _
    (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Integer

    Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" _
    (ByVal hWnd As Integer, ByVal wMsg As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, _
     ByVal lParam As String) As Integer

    Private Declare Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowExA" _
    (ByVal hWnd1 As Integer, ByVal hWnd2 As Integer, ByVal lpsz1 As String, _
     ByVal lpsz2 As String) As Integer

    Private Const WM_SETTEXT As Integer = &HC

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As  _
    System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim hwnd As Integer
        Dim txt As Integer
        Dim text As String

            hwnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, "Description")
            If hwnd <> Nothing Then
                txt = FindWindowEx(hwnd, 0, "Edit", vbNullString)
                If txt <> Nothing Then
                    text = "00000"
                    SendMessage(txt, WM_SETTEXT, 0, text)
                End If
            End If

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: What does this have to do with "Window API Functions", other than the fact that you're using some?

Comment: sorry if i typed the wrong title

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the second parameter to FindWindowEx() called "hwndChildAfter":

> A handle to a child window. The search begins with the next child
>   window in the Z order. The child window must be a direct child window
>   of hwndParent, not just a descendant window.

So you should be able to pass the first textbox handle in to get the next one like this:

```
txt2 = FindWindowEx(hwnd, txt, "Edit", vbNullString)
```

Comment: Sounds like this should work. I have written the code using your comments and will be testing it in the next 2 and half hours and will let you know asap. thanks so much for your input

Comment: You can also pass "txt" to the [GetWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633515(v=vs.85).aspx) API with the GW_HWNDNEXT flag.  "If the specified window is a child window, the handle identifies a sibling window."